# Delete tables in Databricks

Tags: azure, datatable, command, databricks, azure-databricks

I have the list of five tables name. I need to delete rest of all the tables in data bricks, which is not in the list. I don't know what command or method to be used to solve this.
Please help me on this.

Regards,
Manoranjini Muthuraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pyspark code
#list of tables to keep
keep_tables = ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3', 'table_4', 'table_5']
#get list of all tables from my_database
df = spark.sql('show tables in my_database')
#loop thru the tables and if table not in keep_tables then do the operation on each table (drop/delete/count etc). 
#**Careful** the code will drop tables not in the keep list
for t in df.collect():
    if t not in keep_tables:
        #do the table operation (drop/delete/count etc)
        print('operate on table {}'.format(t.tableName))
        spark.sql('drop table my_database.{}'.format(t.tableName)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).